# StringBuiler in place of StringBuffer for appending multiple String with dynamic inputs in EJB

Tags: string, jakarta-ee, ejb, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

According to definition and work "StringBuffer is synchronized, and StringBuilder isn't" in Java

As in project we are using multiple files for handling db operation and in many files we are using StringBuffer for appending String. In some Ejb article, we just come to know that EJB container provide thread safe mechanism.

So we want to know that we can use StringBuiler in place of StringBuffer for appending multiple String with dynamic inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a StringBuffer as a member variable (but if so, why?) or else the question doesn't really make sense.  If you are, then yes, the EJB container ensures only one thread at a time can be accessing a bean instance (unless you're using EJB 3.1 singleton session beans and have used a non-standard concurrency setting), so yes, you just use StringBuilder.

Comment: Yeah we are using StringBuffer as a member variable. And Thanks, it is really valuble.

Answer (score 0):

Both StringBuilder and StringBuffer are mutable (you can modify characters inside them). StringBuilder was introduced in java 1.5. The only difference is thread safety. StringBuffer is thread safe, and hence you can use it in a multi-threaded application. StringBuilder is not thread safe.

So use StringBuilder if you are developing a non-multithreaded application as it performs
better than StringBuffer.

Hope this helps.

Good luck.

Comment: About StringBuffer and StringBuilder are already mention in documentation. Question is to use StringBuilder in case of EJB container. Will it provide synchronized/Thread Safe to StringBuilder?